# is there any way to bind ng-model to multiple input fields uniquely inside a directive?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In my Project i Got a Issue like.I need to bind the user hobbies in the text field.if the user comes with a single hobby he can directly enter the hobby that he has. but when he had multiple then he had to click add multiple hobbies button.that working fine when i am displaying input fields dynamically using directives.but the issue is the value that coming from ng-model for that input field is binding to all input fields.

Here is my code.

Thanks in advance!

### these are the images

this is how i am getting
[image]

this is what i need
[image]

### In HTML

```
<div>
<div id="showHobbyfield"></div>
<input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="ADD HOBBIES"
ng-click="addHoby()">
</div>
```

### In controller

```
$scope.addHoby= function(){
      var compiledeHTML = $compile("<div my-hobby></div>")($scope);
      $("#showHobbyfield").append(compiledeHTML);
    };

$scope.addUser = function(){
$scope.Users= [];

var obj = {
  userhobby : $scope.user.morehobies

  };
    $scope.Users.push(obj);
 menuStorage.put($scope.Users);
```

//menustorage is service to store user in localStorage.

### In directive

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('myHobby', function() {

    return {
      scope : false,
      templateUrl: 'views/my-hobby.html'
    };
  });
```

### this is template: my-hobby.html

```
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" ng-model="user.morehobies" class="form-control" placeceholder="type your hobbies here">

        <div class="close-icon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="padding-left: 6px;"> </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: where is the `user` definition? I mean the controller code for `my-hobby` html

Comment: hoo sorry i missed out some where. i will edit my code, Thanks for reply!

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use a directive here? Seems strange to add your directive programatically later.

Comment: yeah  Ofcourse. i too felt like that but i got a requirement like this to add users hobbies dynamically. i going wrong in the ngmodel. or you can suggest me in the another way of doing this

Comment: when i am typing sports on the input field the value sports is binding in all the input fields when i clicked on the addhobies button.can you help me over here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this i would suggest some other way if its ok with you.

If your hobbies is coming in array, like

```
user.morehobies = ['Reading', 'Writing']
```

or create array for storing hobbies.

then inside directive you can pass that object in directive.

I will use ng-repeat inside directive.

```
<div class="input-group" ng-repeat="h in hobies">
        <input type="text" ng-model="h" class="form-control" placeceholder="type your hobbies here">
      <div class="close-icon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="padding-left: 6px;"> </span>
      </div>
</div>
```

so whenever user clicks on "Add hobbies" then we can add empty string in **hobbies** object in directive.

and whenever user clicks on remove you can remove that item from array.